# How do you have your background behind text?

Tags: html, css, background, html-table, background-image

I'm having trouble placing my background image, in the background of my text. I'm using the code I have but it always ends up placing the image in front of my text. Here is the code:

```
 <html>
</style>
<head>
<title>Testing</title>
</head>
    <h1 style="text-align: center;">
        <img alt="" src="header.png" />
    </h1>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width: 100%">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 50%">
                    <h2>
                        <span style="color: #ffd700;"><span
                            style="background-color: #0000ff;">Unknown</span>
                    </h2>
                </td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td style="width: 50%">
                    <h2>
                        <span style="color: #ffd700;"><span
                            style="background-color: #0000ff;">Unknown</span>
                    </h2>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <h4>
                        <strong>(A bunch of text I had)</strong>
                    </h4>
                    <h4>
                        <strong>(More Text)</strong>
                    </h4>
                    <h4>
                        <strong>(Text)</strong>
                    </h4>
                </td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>
                    <p>
                        <img alt="" src="image.png" />
                    </p>
                    <p style="margin: 0in; margin-bottom: .0001pt">
                        <strong>Person</strong>
                        <o:p></o:p>
                    </p>
                    <p style="margin: 0in 0in 0.0001pt;">
                        <strong>(More text)</strong>
                        <o:p></o:p>
                    </p>
                    <p style="margin: 0in 0in 0.0001pt;">
                        <strong>(More text)</strong>
                        <o:p></o:p>
                    </p>
                    <p style="margin: 0in 0in 0.0001pt;">
                        <strong>(More text)</strong>
                        <o:p></o:p>
                        </span>
                    </p>
                    <p style="margin: 0in; margin-bottom: .0001pt">
                        <strong><a href="www.google.com"(Moretext)></a></strong></a>
                        <o:p></o:p>
                    </p>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
</div>
</html>
```

Forgot to add the background image code I had:

```
<div style="z-index:0;left:0;top:0;width:100%;height:100%">
<img src="background.png" style='width:100%;height:100%'/>
```

Comment: Don't see any code which would make an image a background

Comment: Side note, only one `</html>` and it's the last tag on your page.

Comment: If all your gonna do is vote people down when we have true knowledge that we are attempting to extend to you, then you won't receive assistance in the future.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style="background: url(background.png);">
```

Don't use the `<img>` code - it's unnecessary with this.

And I'd advise you to avoid using `z-index` unless you really need to because if it's the only one it can probably be avoided using positioning or floats.